# Expose only parts of a git repository as public clone, but with full history

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control

We have our code in SVN, but switch to Git now.

The problem is we have this folders:

```
/src/com/something/main
/src/com/something/dev
```

and the Eclipse source folder is set to `/src`.

Only code that is in package `.../main` must become public.

Code in package `.../dev` is unfinished and private.

When code in `.../dev` is finished, we move the class to `.../main` in Eclipse. This is a different Java package, we do not use branches. So this is not a merge.

I tried

```
git filter-branch --index-filter
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch src/com/something/dev'
```

But then all history before the move is lost, files suddenly appear finished by author who moved!

How to split the repository into two branches: branch "secret" has everything, branch "public" has full history of all files in folder `.../main` even when the file was originally in folder `.../dev` which is hidden?

Assume the file history is as follows

```
.../dev/file1 created    moved to .../main/file1 (released)
.../dev/file2 created    but not released
```

then I need public version to show two commits: creation of `.../dev/file1` and the move to the release. And of course any edits done inbetween to this file. The existance/history of `.../dev/file2` should only be in the complete repository. Even worse: some commit edits `file1` and `file2`, but only `file1` is published.

Does git allow this? Having a "secret" branch, but when pushing a file from the secret branch to the main branch, all history is also moved? Or does it commit the final file (without history) to release branch? File renames seem to be very bad supported, too. How does it handle other files in the same commits that are not pushed? Is there a git command to commit a file1 to branch "public" with all history of this file only, not of other files in same commits?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: I'm not asking how to do better. I have 1000 revisions I need convert.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `git mv dev /src/com/something/dev /src/com/something/main`.  That preserves history.  But you don't want to preserve all history, you want a different one.  So you have to separate out the public and private parts of commits that touch never-published files.  And git needs to know about the move (either from `git mv` or because it autodetected the relocation) to have any chance of associating the old file's history with the new path.  Even if that history is revised.

So one starting question might be "what is the intersection of commits that touch both /src/com/something/dev and /src/com/something/main?"

```
git log --reverse --pretty=oneline /src/com/something/main /src/com/something/dev >combined_commits.log
git log --pretty=oneline /src/com/something/dev  >dev_commits.log
git log --pretty=oneline /src/com/something/main >main_commits.log
sort main_commits.log dev_commits.log | uniq -d  >bad_history.log
```

So that final list has all the commits that touched both (but not in the original, i.e. combined_commits.log order).  There is no one command to do what you want, but you might script towards it.  The loose algorithm is:

git rebase -i ${EARLIEST_CONFLICT_HASH}~1

Mark "edit" for all the bad commits, like:

```
...
pick c6d108f Auto-detect catkey vs. barcode
pick 8616c0e Directory cleanup
edit ae885c6 Move registration url to '/register'
pick af5394f Initiate workflow on registration
...
```

Save/exit.  Then during each "edit" phase:

```
git commit /src/*/*/dev  # commit dev stuff separately first
git add /src/*/*/main    
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: The files were already moved long ago. `git mv` does not help me, I won't replay 1000 revisions and do the moves by hand.